# How to change writer format to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

So I found this format of saving csv file and I wanted to know how I can change it to a dataframe?

```
with open('abc123.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Item Name', 'Price', 'Original Price', 'Discount Rate', 'Rating', 'ReviewCount', 'Url'])
        writer.writerows(records)

# records is a list
```

I tried to look for similar questions but I just couldn't seem to find it.

Comment: Write a pandas dataframe to a csv file?  Like `df.to_csv()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what? writing 'records' as dataframe instead of csv?
Then you can use something like:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(records, columns=['Item Name', 'Price', 'Original Price', 'Discount Rate', 'Rating', 'ReviewCount', 'Url'])
```

or

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(records)
df.columns=['Item Name', 'Price', 'Original Price', 'Discount Rate', 'Rating', 'ReviewCount', 'Url']
```

if what you mean is writing a dataframe to csv, then you can use:

```
#df is a DataFrame object
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

specify additional features like separator, unicode,index, header, etc. as you wish.